# mysql php - how to make one of these two?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to execute these two queries from php, is there a way to merge them together in a single query or I have to use a stored procedure?

```
SET @rn=0;
UPDATE `nl_emails` SET `row_num`=(@rn:=@rn+1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want tot achieve by query?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single query, they are completely different statements. But `mysqli::multi_query` can execute multiple queries. Executing them both separately, directly after each other, should achieve the same effect - user variables are connection-specific. You could wrap them into a transaction perhaps, but I don't see that adding much actual benefit here.

Comment: already tried multi_query but that doesn't work; the two queries are executed standalone and I cannot achieve what I need, thanks anyway

Comment: @disk you should self-answer if you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it is possible. We could create @rn in the query but it will be local and the value will be lost from one row to another.
Here is another way of doing the what I believe you want to do.

> ```
> create table nl_emails (id int not null primary key ,row_num int);
> insert into nl_emails values(10,10),(20,20),(30,30);
> ```

> ```
> with cte as(
> select id, row_num, 
> row_number() over (order by id)rn
> from nl_emails)
> update nl_emails join cte on nl_emails.id = cte.id
> set nl_emails.row_num = rn;
> ```

> ```
> select * from nl_emails;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | row_num
> -: | ------:
> 10 |       1
> 20 |       2
> 30 |       3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8cc162b6d8af8c4a47957d393be517d7)*

Comment: Note  that this is valid only for `MySQL 8+`

Comment: unfortunately i'm on mysql5, very old I know but I cannot force the customer to update

Answer (score 0):

So as question marked with `php` tag, you can use PHP PDO solution:

```
<?php

$sql = "SET @rn = 0;
UPDATE nl_emails SET row_num = (@rn:=coalesce(@rn, 0) + 1);";

$pdo->exec($sql);
```

[Test PHP PDO online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/c56ee9a551419805ad1c3c2d658b87c9/php/php81/e3a0fb8c87a54ace26663fcce4b5531e/)

Comment: interesting, thanks! I'll try it, by now is the solution that i prefer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make in one direct query, but you have to check the performance.

Use:

```
UPDATE `nl_emails` n1 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
                     id
            FROM  nl_emails, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
) as t1 on n1.id=t1.id
SET n1.`row_num`=t1.num;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf7d4a9243eed3c3e3aeb934846294b7

The key part is the cross join used

```
SELECT  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
        id
FROM  nl_emails, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
;
```